# Way to drag/drop attachment files from Java Swing application to Outlook without invoking Outlook client application

Tags: java, swing, outlook, drag-and-drop

I am investigating the feasibility of drag/drop files **into** outlook email from a Java Swing application.  I have found several examples of dragging **from** outlook, but I want to do the opposite. Currently, the application relies on the Outlook desktop client for this.  I would like to replace this functionality with a drag/drop ActiveX control (yes, this is an old legacy application) or something similar.  The current solution relies on Outlook seat licenses for the desktop client, and that is the part that I am wanting to replace without opening the desktop client.

So far I am in the exploratory phase of this project.  What I want to do may not even be an option within the parameters of the application.

Any ideas/experience is much appreciated.

Comment: I am not sure I understand the requirement - you want to drag **to** Outlook, but you don't want to open/use Outlook. How is that possible?

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko I'm looking for a way to drag/drop attachments to an area of the enterprise application and let an ActiveX control send an email with attachment without opening the desktop client.  The web client should be fine though.

Comment: [Sending Emails with Java](https://www.baeldung.com/java-email)

Comment: So you don't want to use Outlook, you only want to send a message with attachment to some Exchange mailbox, right? You can use EWS or Graph for that.

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko thank you - this looks exactly like what i am needing.

Comment: Keep in mind that sending though SMTP and an Office 365 server won't work unless you enable Basic auth for the tenant.